# Веб сервер на flask, не работает регистрация, бразуер не перекидывает на страницу

Tags: python, сервер, flask

У меня есть код регистрацию и авторизацию:

```
@app.route('/reg/', methods=['post', 'get'])
def register_acc():
if 'login' and 'password' in session:
    return redirect('/')

if request.method == 'POST':
    login = request.form.get('Login')
    password = request.form.get('pass')
    nickname = request.form.get('so2Nick')
    id = request.form.get('so2id')

    acc = LobbyFiender.User(password, id, login)
    acc.AddId(id)
    acc.AddNickname(nickname)
    acc.AddLogin(login)
    if acc.CheckForRegister():
        acc.registerRequest()
        LobbyFiender.save()
        session['login'] = login
        session['password'] = password
        session['gameid'] = id
        session['nick'] = nickname
        return redirect('/')

return render_template("register.html")


@app.route('/login/', methods=['post', 'get'])
def auth_acc():
if 'login' and 'password' in session:
    return redirect('/')

if request.method == 'POST':
    login = request.form.get('login')
    nick = request.form.get('nick')
    password = request.form.get('pass')
    gameid = request.form.get('id')

    acc = LobbyFiender.User(password, id, login)
    acc.auth()
    if acc.authed:
        session['login'] = login
        session['password'] = password
        session['gameid'] = gameid
        session['nick'] = nick
        return redirect('/')

return render_template('auth.html')
```

при нажатии на кнопку регистрации, мне выдает бразуер Chrome что сайт выполнил слишком много переадресаций и не выдал мне главную страницу сайта, что делать?

Comment: 1) Почините табуляции. 2) А где обработчик запроса корня сайта? 3) Сами `html`-и тоже интересно бы посмотреть. А вообще похоже у вас переадресация зацикливается.